# Pressing Shift triggers Expose

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I don't know how I got my computer like this, but somehow pressing either shift button causes Expose to open. What might be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences / Keyboard and there is a tab near the top that says 'shortcuts', click on that. Now you see all the keyboard shortcuts. Find one for Expose and change it.